# Using ActionBarCompat and requestWindowFeature

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

so far i had no  bigger problems moving from ActionBarSherlock to ActionBarCompat. On my Nexus 4 it works pretty good. As i began to test on my older Nexus One running 2.3.6 i ran in an problem when i rotate the device. I request an Window feature to show the intermediate progress in the ActionBar:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(android.view.Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    requestWindowFeature(android.view.Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);

    setupActionBar(getSupportActionBar());

}
```

This works pretty good on Jelly Bean.

On 2.3.6 is get this Stack Trace:

```
08-12 13:34:09.242: E/AndroidRuntime(4602): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-12 13:34:09.242: E/AndroidRuntime(4602): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.app.packagename/net.app.fragment.CustomActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
08-12 13:34:09.242: E/AndroidRuntime(4602):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
08-12 13:34:09.242: E/AndroidRuntime(4602):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-12 13:34:09.242: E/AndroidRuntime(4602):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2832)
08-12 13:34:09.242: E/AndroidRuntime(4602):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-12 13:34:09.242: E/AndroidRuntime(4602):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
08-12 13:34:09.242: E/AndroidRuntime(4602):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-12 13:34:09.242: E/AndroidRuntime(4602):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-12 13:34:09.242: E/AndroidRuntime(4602):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-12 13:34:09.242: E/AndroidRuntime(4602):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-12 13:34:09.242: E/AndroidRuntime(4602):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-12 13:34:09.242: E/AndroidRuntime(4602):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-12 13:34:09.242: E/AndroidRuntime(4602):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-12 13:34:09.242: E/AndroidRuntime(4602):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-12 13:34:09.242: E/AndroidRuntime(4602): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
08-12 13:34:09.242: E/AndroidRuntime(4602):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:181)
08-12 13:34:09.242: E/AndroidRuntime(4602):     at android.app.Activity.requestWindowFeature(Activity.java:2729)
08-12 13:34:09.242: E/AndroidRuntime(4602):     at net.app.fragment.BaseFragmentActivity.onCreate(BaseFragmentActivity.java:50)
08-12 13:34:09.242: E/AndroidRuntime(4602):     at net.app.fragment.CustomActivity.onCreate(CustomActivity.java:55)
08-12 13:34:09.242: E/AndroidRuntime(4602):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-12 13:34:09.242: E/AndroidRuntime(4602):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
08-12 13:34:09.242: E/AndroidRuntime(4602):     ... 12 more
08-12 13:34:12.092: I/Process(4602): Sending signal. PID: 4602 SIG: 9
```

Anyone knows how to fix this ?

regards

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Call `supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_...)`.

See http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `supportRequestWindowFeature(WindowCompat.FEATURE_xxx)`

i.e. You also need to use `WindowCompat.FEATURE_xxx` instead of `Window.FEATURE_xxx` for backward comptability.

Answer (score 0):

For those, who don't call `requestWindowFeature()` method but still get the exception, try this workaround:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        //dummy workaround
    }
    setContentView(getLayoutResId());
```

see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60841

Answer (score 0):

Error log clearly says 'requestFeature() must be called before adding content'. So you have to call 'super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);' after 'requestWindowFeature' calls. And there is no need to call supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_...) as mentioned above. See the working code below.

```
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```